# Active link not being removed from

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using a 3 tab menu when active tag being on form 1 when page loads. When each tab is clicked the active tag should be removed and applied to the new selected form. `form1 form2 form3`

This works fine when I do not add the forms to each tab. But when I do add the forms the problem persist.

I am making the forms with `contact 7` the wordpress plugin. Would my javascript be conflicting with something existing?

This is my javascript? Is there a way I could change it to make it work better with `contact 7 plugin`?

```
  <script>
    $('#myForm a').click(function (e) {
        var tab = $(this);
        if(tab.parent('li').hasClass('active')){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $(".tab-pane").removeClass('active');
                tab.parent('li').removeClass('active');
            },1);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

You can see the site im working on [Click Here](http://www.wuno.com/project)
The forms on the home page in the tabs.

Comment: There's an error in your javascript for flickr, check your console log.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. I will see if I can fix that and hopefully fix the problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your logic by removing the active class on all of it's sibling `li` elements and then add the active class to the one that was clicked.

```
$('#myForm a').click(function (e) {
    var tab = $(this);
    tab.parent('li').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    tab.parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But ya it still just adds active and wont remove them.

Comment: Actually it makes it to the new tabs dont become active.

Comment: It works fine for me on Chrome. Maybe I don't understand your problem completely.

Comment: When the page loads form1 should be active. when form 2 is clicked form one should remove active class and add it to form2. Also the page is super long from all the forms. Once you click each form the just stack instead of overlapping hidden